# What are the Fresnel formulas for acoustics?

Tags: acoustics, reflection, refraction

While it's not too difficult to derive [Snell's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law) for acoustics e.g. from Huygen's principle like for light, I find surprisingly little resources on an equivalent to Fresnel formulas linking the reflected and refracted amplitudes, mostly limited to perpendicular incidence and sound intensity in dependence of acoustical impedance, but what are the formulas for e.g. pressure or density continuity at arbitrary angles of incidence?